# Android: Scheduling a repeating task for short time intervals isn't working

Tags: android, alarmmanager

In Android, I have an activity which schedules a task(showing a notification) to repeat for every 10 or 15 mins even if the app is closed or killed.

I have tried to schedule it using `AlarmManager` with `alarmManager.setExact`, `alarmManager.set` and `alarmManager.setRepeating` and none of them fired the event at exact time. There is a lot of delay in firing the event. Sometimes it fire at exact time and sometimes there will be delay. The delay ranges from 15 mins to several hours.

I saw the android docs saying that AlarmManager will delay the events starting from Lollipop 5.1. I have tried it with `Handlers` as well as `TimerTask` and `Timer`, but they get killed immediately when app is killed.

Is there any alternate solution which runs for short interval times and runs in the background too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) and a [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Start a service and initialize the count down timer for 10 to 15 minutes as you would prefer when the timer finishes you reinitialize the same timer and show notification in onFinish method of the timer.

This way you will be showing notifications even when the app is closed.

Comment: But i guess its not easy to restart a service automatically when the app/service gets killed starting from lollipop.

Comment: Yes it is not easy and the feature you want to implement is also kind of unique. So you will have to choose the hard way if you want to accurately implement the solution.
You may have to broadcast the service stopping and restart it in the broadcast reciever.

Answer (score 0):

Updated and working example:

This one sets and alarm for spesific day and time. Then repeats every 3 minutes.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 03);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.TUESDAY);

        Intent dailyIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);

        PendingIntent mondayIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1000, dailyIntent, 0);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), mondayIntent);
        } else {
            System.out.println("------------------------");
        }
    }
}
```

AlarmActivity:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    Intent intent;
    PendingIntent pendingIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm_activity);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1000, intent, 0);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() +
                        60 * 1000 * 3, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
Also don't forget to set your alarms on system reboot and package (your app) update.

Comment: @DileepPerla it is a working & tested example. If you share your code then we may detect what is wrong.

Comment: can you try it for 10min interval and check if its working, because it is working for long time intervals, its even working which is scheduled one in the morning and another in the evening, but not for less intervals like 10min or less than that

Comment: let me try it and will get back to you after sometime

Comment: this isn't working either, as android docs clearly says alarm-managers doesn't fire at exact time and causes delay, I am just looking for alternatives which runs even when app is closed.